# Important ODE Solutions for Solving PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Which ODEs pop up most often in the study of Partial Differential Equations such as the Heat Eq, Laplace Eq, Wave Eq, etc. At least in the homogeneous case. What are their solutions? I'm going to take an exam today in PDE 1, but I want to make sure that I know most of the important ODEs that I will need to solve. For example, one that pops up everywhere is:

$${du\over dt} = -kuh \implies e^{-ku}$$ where $h$ is an eigenvalue. 
Or the similar space-dependent ODE for the heat equation.

When do we get trigonometric functions for eigenfunctions? When do we get hyperbolic trigonometric functions? Is there some regularity

Comment: I think you meant $u' = -ku$

Comment: Are you requesting for a list of such ODE's?

Answer (score 3):

You can sometimes think of the elementary functions as solutions to certain ODEs, for example $\sin kx$ and $\cos kx$ are both solutions to 
$$y''+k^2y=0$$
and $\sinh kx$ and $\cosh kx$ are solutions to
$$y''-k^2y=0$$

There are more "obscure" but useful functions too such as Bessel functions $y=J_k(x)$ which satisfy
$$x^2 y''+xy'+(x^2-k^2)y=0$$
and is useful for the radial coordinate often in polar coordinates, and Legendre polynomials $y=P_n(x)$ which satisfy 
$$\left[(1-x^2)y'\right]'+n(n+1)y=0$$

which are often useful for the angular parts in polar coordinates. There are many others too though including Laguerre and Hermite polynomails, but each has its associated ODE.